# Illegal characters in path. Error when using Skip and Take with IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable

Hi there I have the following action in my controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<SurveyResult> myresult = filterData();
    totalCount = myresult.Count<SurveyResult>();
    ViewBag.totalCount = totalCount;
    //myresult = myresult.Skip<SurveyResult>(100 * pageIndex).Take<SurveyResult>(100);
    return View(myresult);
}
```

Here is my view

```
@model IEnumerable<SurveyResult>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Survey Results";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <table class="std-tbl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    DEL
                </th>
                ...

                <th>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x, new { pageIndex = ViewBag.index })
    </table>
}
```

I have a partial view for SurveyResult but I am not including it because i don't think its relevant.  Here is my question.  The above code is working fine but as soon as I uncomment the following line

```
myresult = myresult.Skip<SurveyResult>(100 * pageIndex).Take<SurveyResult>(100);
```

I get "Illegal characters in path. " I think it can find the partialView for SurveyResult.  I don't understand why it can find it when the above line is commented but it can't when its uncommented?  Thank you.

Here is my stack trace

```
[ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.]
   System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path) +126
   System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2) +38
   System.Web.Compilation.DiskBuildResultCache.GetPreservedDataFileName(String cacheKey) +27
   System.Web.Compilation.DiskBuildResultCache.GetBuildResult(String cacheKey, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +14
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetBuildResultFromCacheInternal(String cacheKey, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +200
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +51
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +68
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +111
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +125
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String virtualPath) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine.FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, String virtualPath) +41
   System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 locations, String name, String controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]& searchedLocations) +150
   System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations) +304
   System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName, Boolean useCache) +130
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<FindPartialView>b__7(IViewEngine e) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths) +127
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName) +170
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.ExecuteTemplate(HtmlHelper html, ViewDataDictionary viewData, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, GetViewNamesDelegate getViewNames, GetDefaultActionsDelegate getDefaultActions) +418
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, ExecuteTemplateDelegate executeTemplate) +1117
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, TemplateHelperDelegate templateHelper) +117
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, Object additionalViewData) +57
   ASP._Page_Views_SurveyResult_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Source\Test\Admin\Views\SurveyResult\Index.cshtml:163
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +207
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +81
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +19
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +65
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +220
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +303
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +260
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8969117
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Here is the source Error:
```

Line 161:            
Line 162:        
**Line 163:        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x, new { pageIndex = ViewBag.index })**
Line 164:    
Line 165:}

Comment: just FYI (unrelated to your question) you don't need to supply the generic type parameters in most cases, it can be inferred from the type of the `IEnumerable`

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I just changed to just do skip or take and I got the same error for both

Comment: yeah, the error is definitely happening because you're getting a real class back from LINQ; see @SLaks answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`DisplayFor` is looking for a view named after the name of the EF-generated implementation classes, which contain illegal characters.

Try calling `.ToList()` in the controller.

Comment: That did it.  Why is does it work if I don't call take and/or skip?

Comment: Because then the type is `DbSet<T>`, which is well-named.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with lazy loading?

Comment: @Phil: It might.  I'm not sure under what circumstances EF generates its own classes.

Comment: I was doing public IEnumerable<SomeType> SomeType { get { return items.OfType<SomeType>(); } } and having the same weird error. After using a List and the ToList() method was fixed, yet no idea WHY or how would I found it if @SLaks isn't around ... thanks.

Comment: The `ToList()` call did it for me as well, but not because of EF classes. Instead it had to do with anonymous classes generated by `yield` blocks in the viewmodel. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27800743/498403.

Comment: Bizarre!  I had this, but it only showed itself in Safari for iPad.  Every other browser inc. Chrome on iPad was fine.