# Illegal characters in path depending on User-Agent?

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, fiddler, user-agent

I have two identical calls to ASP.NET, the only difference is the User-Agent. I used Fiddler to reproduce the issue.

The HTTP request line is:

```
PUT http://localhost/API/es/us/havana/club/tickets/JiWOUUMxukGVWwVXQnjgfw%7C%7C214 HTTP/1.1
```

Works with:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; Nexus 10 Build/JSS15Q) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2307.2 Safari/537.36
```

Fails with:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A4345d Safari/600.1.4
```

Everything else is 100% the same.

Comment: How does it fail? What is the returned status code? Any error trace on server side?

Comment: Server Error in '/Api' Application.
Illegal characters in path. ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.]
   System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional) +13766780
   System.IO.Path.GetExtension(String path) +28
   System.Web.WebPages.DefaultDisplayMode.TransformPath(String virtualPath, String suffix) +49
   System.Web.WebPages.DefaultDisplayMode.GetDisplayInfo(HttpContextBase httpContext, String virtualPath, Func`2 virtualPathExists) +33
   System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.GetDisplayInfoForVirtualPath(String virtualPath, HttpContextBase,..

Comment: Let me clarify the issue seems to be unrelated to Fiddler. I just used fiddler to trace the calls.

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487032/user-agent-causes-mvc-displayfor-argumentexception-illegal-characters-in-path

Comment: Hi, it was never getting inside a hook I could find (message handlers, authorization attributes, etc) so I decided to base64 encode the key. It seems that the combination of double pipes (||) and the agent were the problem. The original key was JiWOUUMxukGVWwVXQnjgfw||214 before the http encode. Thanks for your advice..

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the root cause was MVC's MultipleViews and DisplayMode providers. This allows MVC apps to magically pick up device-specific views; e.g.
custom.cshtml
customer.mobile.cshtml

This article has a good explanation of the functionality as well as details how to turn it off:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/august/cutting-edge-creating-mobile-optimized-views-in-asp-net-mvc-4-part-2-using-wurfl

I fixed this by adding Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages package to my project and adding a call to this code in my startup (application_start in global.asax or if using OWIN, the method decordated w/ OwinStartup attribute):

```
public static void RegisterDisplayModes()
{
    // MVC has handy helper to find device-specfic views. Ain't no body got     time for that.
    dynamic modeDesktop = new DefaultDisplayMode("") { ContextCondition = (c => { return true; }) };
    dynamic displayModes = DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes;
    displayModes.Clear();
    displayModes.Add(modeDesktop);
}
```

Comment: Looking at `DisplayModeProvider` code, we can simply instantiate the default mode this way: `var modeDesktop = new DefaultDisplayMode();`, it will be functionally identical. By the way, why using dynamics? This kills compilation checks: better use explicit typing or implicit `var` typing.